# Where is the Yii2 autocomplete class located?

Tags: yii2

I have used:

```
echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'file',
        'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => ['USA', 'RUS'],
    ],
]);
```

But I get the error:

```
Class 'AutoComplete' not found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should install [Yii 2 Jquery UI extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui) first.
The full class name with namespace is [yii\jui\Autocomplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-autocomplete.html).
You can use it like this:

```
use yii\jui\Autocomplete;

...

echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'file',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => ['USA', 'RUS'],
    ],
]);
```

or

```
echo yii\jui\AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'file',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => ['USA', 'RUS'],
    ],
]);
```